# How to make UIView match size of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel that has auto layout applied to it as well as its preferredWidth changed to ensure it is formatted properly. I want a UIView to be 'underneath' it and match the size of the label. Setting the frame.size of the UIView to the label.frame.size does not work as it does not consider the auto layout that is occurring.

I am thinking there must be a way to match the constraints of the UILabel and then adjust size after that. However I don't think this can work, as the UILabel's formatting is not relevant to the separate UIView.

Note: the text is known past runtime because it is dependent on information from a web server.

Relevant Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageTableViewCell

    cell.messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.frame.size.width - 35
    preferredWidth = cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth

    cell.messageLabel.text = friends[indexPath!.row]
    cell.messageLabel.sizeToFit()
    cell.messageLabel.setNeedsDisplay()

    //cell.msgBubble.frame.size.width = preferredWidth
    //cell.msgBubble.

    cell.msgBubble.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.msgBubble.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    return cell
    // Configure the cell...
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

    var sampleLabel = UILabel()
    sampleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    sampleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    sampleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredWidth

    sampleLabel.text = friends[indexPath!.row]
    sampleLabel.sizeToFit()
    sampleLabel.setNeedsDisplay()

    return sampleLabel.intrinsicContentSize().height + 10

}
```

Comment: Just set the `UIView`'s constraints to exactly equal the size and position of the `UILabel`. If there are no other constraints on the `UIView` it will always align with the `UILabel` perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have added enough constraint for the label. Now we need to add constraints for the view to resize according to the label.

Select both the label and the view, you can do it in the side bar in Xcode. (cmd + mouse click)

[image]

Then add constraints. You can enter whatever values you like. If you get warnings, you can update the frame or update the constraints.

[image]

Comment: Normally this would solve the issue if the layout was understood at runtime. However, the text in the UILabel is determined past runtime, so my UIView is basically stretched to the default size of the UILabel, rather than to size that the UILabel is when there is content inside of it (which is formatted using the code in that first method)

Comment: @user3784622 I have made a small project. If I understand you question correctly, this would be helpful. I have added it at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @user3784622 I guess maybe you should set the constrains yourself, instead of calling sizeToFit(). I used an alternative method in the project above.

Comment: @user3784622 I have modified the project. If you have downloaded it before seeing this message, please download again.